# How to change resulting Json when serializing, more or less globally, if class declarations can not be changed?

Tags: java, json, gson

Assume that:

- there is a **bunch** of Java objects that you need to pass - for example - to some API
- you are not willing or can not change declaration for those objects
- unfortunately API requires something that is not declared in those objects

As an example (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53194710/6413377) question) there is a simple class:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Login {
    private final String username, password; 
}
```

However, API expects JSON like:

```
{
  "username": "uname",
  "password": "pword",
  "version": 1
}
```

and this same problem applies to all other 99 classes: those need also field `version` with value 1 in serialized JSON.

There are some solutions that require either low level string manipulation or adding lots of boilerplate code but what would be the **generic** way to deal with this issue with GSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, to have Gson to serialize (or to deserialize) bunch of different types of objects having same type of adapting the best way to avoid registering lots of adapters or altering class declarations is to make benefit of `TypeAdapterFactory`.

It is not itself bound to any `Type` or `Class` but decides per type which `TypeAdapter` to return when Gson bumps into some object to serialize (or deserialize). Using `TypeAdaterFactory` frees code from registering lots of `TypeAdapter`s.

**Secondly** and naturally, to avoid creating many `TypeAdapter`s the solution is to make a generic type of `TypeAdapter` whenever possible.

Starting from the generic `TypeAdapter` in questions case it might be like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
private class GenericTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {

    // typeToken is needed when deserializing
    private final TypeToken<T> typeToken;
    private final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
        // Altering could be done with some low level string manipulation
        // but JsonObject makes altering object more safe.
        // Feel free to comment for better way to instantiate it,
        // this is just for an example.
        JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(value)
                            ,JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();
        // alter jsonObject in any way needed,
        // here is only added version information
        jsonObject.addProperty("version", 1);
        out.jsonValue(gson.toJson(jsonObject));
    }

    @Override
    public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        // maybe needless to mention but mention still:
        // here it is possible to init object in a way 
        // that provided JSON solely does not make possible
        return gson.fromJson(in, typeToken.getType());
    }
}
```

Then the `TypeAdapterFactory`. It is quite simple but pay attention to the comments in example code. As mentioned before `TypeAdapterFactory` is responsible of returning correct `TypeAdapter` per object. Although it is meant to apply to a **bunch** of types it might not be meant to apply to **all** the types. Most simple `TypeAdapterFactory`:

```
public class GenericTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // here should be checked if the passed type needs any custom 
        // adapter and if it needs then decide  which adapter to return
        // or in case of no customization needed return null for default
        // adapter.
        // decision can be made for example by
        // * type itself
        // * package name
        // * if type implements / extends some super type
        return new GenericTypeAdapter<>(type);
    }       
}
```

Usage would then simply be:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new GenericTypeAdapterFactory())
    .setPrettyPrinting()
    .create()
```

**Note**: I prepared this answer originally to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53194710/6413377) but since it later appeared to be  Kotlin(?) based I felt better to create a more generic Q&A dealt with Java.